# How to rename a partition

Tags: command-line, partitioning

I have partitions that I would like to rename.  What are the terminal commands to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can re-label file systems with Gnome Disks:

[image: Gnome Disks option menu]
[image: Gnome Disks rename dialogue]

If you really want to use the command line, the command depends on the affected file system type. For ext2/3/4 it's

```
sudo e2label <DEVICE> <NEW_LABEL>
```

In a similar fashion there are `fatlabel`, `exfatlabel`, `ntfslabel`, `btrfs filesystem label`, `swaplabel` for other file system types with the same command syntax.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line install the labeling program depending on the filesystem type. Here are all the different installation commands for each filesystem type:

```bash
sudo apt-get install mtools             # MS-DOS
sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs          # NTFS
sudo apt-get install e2fsprogs          # Ext2
sudo apt-get install jfsutils           # JFS
sudo apt-get install reiserfsprogs      # ReiserFS
sudo apt-get install xfsprogs           # XFS
```

Identify your partition using:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Then, for an example partition `sdX`:

- for FAT32:

  ```
  sudo mlabel -i /dev/sdX ::"new_label"
  ```
- for NTFS:

  ```
  sudo ntfslabel /dev/sdX new_label
  ```
- for exFAT:

  ```
  sudo exfatlabel /dev/sdX new_label
  ```
- for ext2/3/4:

  ```
  sudo e2label /dev/sdX new_label
  ```